# Windows NX client can't connect to FreeNX server

Tags: centos6, freenx

After my Centos 6 server was powered down without a clean shutdown, I can't connect to the FreeNX service. I get errors like:

```
xrdb: No such file or directory
xrdb: Can't open display ':1001'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the /tmp/.X2-lock file had to be deleted. The following command might help anyone else in the future:

```
sudo rm /tmp/.X*-lock
```